# Multi row update statement where record = composite key

Tags: sql, sql-server

**yes I know the table names have been changed as with the fields names so it may be a bit confusing**

I am trying to do a batch update, effectively I want to pass in a list of XXXX and YYYY that together make a composite key, I want to update all records that match the list of composite keys, the bellow statement will update a single record where all conditions are met, but I would like to modify the where clause to be something along the lines of an IN statement that will allow me to update multiple records... I was thinking of adjusting it to be

```
IN ('1','2','3')
IN ('5','6','7')
```

but this poses another issue as with the concept a composite key they pairs 1-5, 2-6, 3-7 are valid however any other combination would be invalid...

is there anyway I can accomplish this by inserting an IN statement or equivalent in place of XXXX and YYYY

```
  UPDATE Table

  SET   id = 99,
        status_id = 45,
        change_date = GetDate(),
        reason = (SELECT Meaning FROM T2 WHERE code = @StatusCode),
        d_id = T2.d_id
  FROM
        Job
        JOIN T2 ON gid = T2.gid
              AND j_id = T2.Ref_id

  WHERE T2.Status = 0
                           /**** this and is supposed to match a composite key ****/
        AND d_id = XXXX
        AND [uid] = YYYY
```

Comment: Mutli row update syntax tends to be backend specific so you should include that with your question. Also you say you want to pass a list of values. That's not only backend specific but the approach would be different on different clients as well. So you'll need to include the client you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t
SET     id = 99
FROM    (
        VALUES
        ('xxx', 'yyy'),
        ('zzz', 'ttt')
        ) v (x, y)
JOIN    mytable t
ON      t.d_id = x
        AND t.[uid] = y
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to concatenate both columns and use that to compare the pair as if it was a single column:

```
 where convert(varchar, d_id) + ' ' + convert(varchar, [uid]) 
       in ('1 5', '2 6', '3 7')
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aecea/2

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table_name
SET column_to_update = new_value
WHERE (composite_key_col1, composite_key_col2) IN
    ((value1_col1, value1_col2),
     (value2_col1, value2_col2),
     (value3_col1, value3_col2));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.